# No delegage callback method called , flurry (9.2.1) integration , ios, objective c, xcode 9

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

i am  using flurry native ads integration in one of the ios projects, it was working fine earlier, but suddenly i found, since last few days that flurry doesn't give any callback. no delegate method invoked.

here is an integration code:

```js
- (void)initFlurrySDK {

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        int FlurryLogLevel = FlurryLogLevelDebug;
        [Flurry startSession:kFlurryAPIKEY
          withSessionBuilder:[[[FlurrySessionBuilder new]
                               withCrashReporting:YES]
                              withLogLevel:FlurryLogLevel]];
        

        NSLog(@"flurry SDK version: %@",[Flurry getFlurryAgentVersion]);
    });
}
    -(void)RequestFlurryad{ //calling from main thread only..
    
        FlurryAdNative *fnativeAd = [[FlurryAdNative alloc] initWithSpace:@<ad_unit_name>];
        self.nativeAd = fnativeAd;

        //Assign the FlurryAdNativeDelegate
        [self.nativeAd setAdDelegate:(id)self];

        //UIViewController used for presentation of the full screen after the user clicks on the ad
        fnativeAd.viewControllerForPresentation = [[VCManager sharedManager] topViewController].navigationController;


        //Request the ad from Flurry.
        [self.nativeAd fetchAd];
    
}
//delegate methods...
- (void) adNativeDidFetchAd:(FlurryAdNative *)nativeAd1{
    
}
- (void) adNative:(FlurryAdNative*) nativeAd1 adError:(FlurryAdError) adError errorDescription:(NSError*) errorDescription{
    
}
```

Comment: same integration works for other apps, sample app, but for one app only, we are not getting any callbacks, and it was working earlier, but since last few days, we are not getting any callbacks :(

Comment: also i am sure that <ad_unit_name> mentioned in integration code above is exactly matching whats mentioned in flurry dashboard.

Comment: 2018-10-17 16:55:34.957256+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry_iOS_234_9.2.0

2018-10-17 16:55:38.080961+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry: IAP Reporting enabled[0]

2018-10-17 16:55:38.081151+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry: startSession called for the first time
2018-10-17 16:55:38.081229+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry: Start session called with apiKey[API_KEY_VALUE]
2018-10-17 16:55:38.081470+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_234_9.2.0]

Comment: 2018-10-17 16:55:38.081562+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry: crash reporting enabled
2018-10-17 16:55:38.098308+0530 AppName[1697:218835] Flurry: Trim white space and use apiKey[API_KEY_VALUE]
2018-10-17 16:55:38.098625+0530 AppName[1697:218835] flurry SDK version: Flurry_iOS_234_9.2.0